# Show that series converges by estimating number of partitions into distinct parts

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, analytic-number-theory, integer-partitions

I need some help with solving the following problem: Let $Q(n)$ be the number of partitions of $n$ into distinct parts. Show that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{Q(n)}{2^n}$$ is convergent by estimating $Q(n)$ in some way. I have been trying to do this for a few days now, but without succeeding. Notice that if we only want to show that the series converges and don't care about which method we use, we can do this by considering the infinite product $\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac{1}{2^n}\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

If $a_1 < \dotsb < a_k$ is a distinct partition of $n$ of size $k$, we must have that $a_j \geq j$, and so
$$
n
= \sum_{j=1}^k a_j
\geq \sum_{j=1}^k j
\geq \frac{k^2}{2}.
$$

Thus, any ordered partition of $n$ must have $k \leq \sqrt{2n}$, and so we have that
\begin{align*}
Q(n)
&= \#\{\text{distinct partitions of }n\} \\
&\leq \#\{\text{partitions of $n$ of size at most $\sqrt{2n}$}\} \\
&\leq \#\{\text{ordered partitions of $n$ of size at most $\sqrt{2n}$}\}.
\end{align*}

But the number of ordered partitions of $n$ of size at most $k$ is $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$ by the standard stars-and-bars argument, so that we have
\begin{align*}
Q(n)
&\leq \binom{n + \lfloor\sqrt{2n}\rfloor - 1}{\lfloor\sqrt{2n}\rfloor - 1} \\
&\leq (n + \sqrt{2n}- 1)^{\sqrt{2n}-  1} \\
&\leq \exp\{\sqrt{2n}\log(n + \sqrt{2n})\} \\
&\lesssim \exp\Bigl\{n \log\frac{3}{2}\Bigr\}.
\end{align*}

Therefore, for large enough $n$, we have that $Q(n)/2^n \leq (3/4)^n$, which is summable.

Comment: Ah, thanks! This seems to be precisely the kind of solution I was looking for. I can follow along with everything you've done, except for the very last step. Are we saying that $\exp{\left(\sqrt{2n}\log{(n+\sqrt{2n})}\right)}\leq\exp{\left(n\log{\frac{3}{2}}\right)}$ eventually? Or what is happening?

Comment: Yes, exactly! It follows form the fact that $\sqrt{2n}\log(n + \sqrt{2n}) = o(n)$, and so for any $A > 0$, we have for large enough $n$ that $\sqrt{2n}\log(n + \sqrt{2n})  \leq An$. I just chose $A = \log(3/2)$ to be a simple value $<\log 2$ that thus ensures that $Q(n)/2^n$ is summable

Comment: Right, of course! Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Let $p(n)$ be the unrestricted partition function. Then we have $Q(n)\le p(n)$. Note that for $|z|<1$

$$
1+\sum_{n\ge1}p(n)z^n=\prod_{k\ge1}(1-z^k)^{-1},
$$

so we have

$$
\sum_{n\ge1}{Q(n)\over2^n}\le1+\sum_{n\ge1}p(n)\left(\frac12\right)^n=\prod_{k\ge1}\left(1-{1\over2^k}\right)^{-1}<\infty.
$$